# asp.net File.Copy Lock

Tags: asp.net, locking

I have an Asp.net page which allows file uploads and then copies the newly uploaded file to another folder. So far so good. Problem is that the copied file is used in the other folder for some other needs (e.g. using FileStream to open the copied file). But asp.net puts a lock on the copied file. I can't even open the copied file using Windows Explorer so long as the Visual Studio's builtin web server is running. I get an error like:

The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot.....pdf' because it is being used by another process

Here is partial code:

```
 System.IO.File.Copy(targetFolder_live + "\\" + finalfilename, targetFolder_encr + "\\" + finalfilename);

 createpreviewdoc(finalfilename);
////inside the createpreviewdoc function
FileStream stream = new FileStream(targetFolder_encr + "/" + file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);//Fails with the error!
```

So what can be done to remove the lock in the same page load? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt the copy in a different fashion.

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("PathToOriginal");
fileInfo.CopyTo("MyNewLocation");

File.OpenText("MyNewLocation"); // works for me
```

Comment: oops! FileStream stream = new FileStream(targetFolder_encr + "/" + file + "_encr.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

Comment: FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(targetFolder_live + "\\" + finalfilename);
                fileInfo.CopyTo(targetFolder_encr + "\\" + finalfilename); //*** Still the same error***

Comment: Is there some stream opening the file in your preview method that's not getting closed?

Comment: hmmm. Only thing I can think of is the Windows Explorer has that folder copied folder open. Let me close that and relaunch the Visual Studio webserver... Thanks!

Comment: Fixed it. My own mistake. Just above the FileStream code, I had this: PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(targetFolder_encr + "/" + file); and so this was the 'process' putting a lock. Changing to PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(targetFolder_live + "/" + file); fixed it. BTW, this is iTextSharp being used to create encrypted PDF files in a different folder. Your 'Comment' about another process helped. Thank you!